# C++ Playing Sound Lag

Tags: c++, audio

For my program I am making pac-man. Every time the pac-man eats a dot I want to play the munching sound. I already know how to play the sound but it causes lag too much lag. The lag is about 0.5 seconds but overall it slows down my game a bunch. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment (lib , "winmm.lib") // Used for sound
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     PlaySound(TEXT("Sounds\\pacman chomp.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNC);
     system("pause");
}
```

Comment: If memory serves, you probably want `waveOutPrepareHeader` and `waveOutWrite`. The basic idea is that you load a buffer of sound data from the file into memory and prepare it for playback. Then when you need to play it, it's waiting and ready for immediate playback.

Comment: how would I go within this route?

Comment: Reading the docs for waveOutPrepareheader and waveOutWrite would be a good start (though @Ron Kuper raises a good point as well).

Comment: how would you use directSound instead then?

Comment: You probably want to start from [DirectSoundCreate8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.directsoundcreate8.aspx), and read the associated documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you want real "twitch time" audio you should probably look at DirectSound, that's what it was created for. The waveOutXXX APIs are better than PlaySound, but DirectSound is better still.

Comment: Google DirectSound tutorial, lots of information out there.